# Google Transliteration API: How to take the input & save the output in a text file?

Tags: java, google-api, transliteration

Greetings All;

I need to use google translitrate api in a java application.

What I have done till now is to import the sample in the library "*gwt-language-1.1.0*" that called "*hellolanguage*" in the netbeans, then I added the required libraries/jars.

It worked fine like this demo:
[hellolanguage Demo](http://gwt.google.com/samples/hellolanguage-1.1.0/HelloLanguage.html)
but on my localhost.

what I want to do is to transliterate data from "inputfile.txt" for example and put the output in an "outputfile.txt".

I don't know how to implement this idea?

I'll be glad if you help me.

Best regards;

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at the Java IO API, for which there is a good tutorial at Oracle. [This part](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html) of the tutorial will be particularly useful, and should provide some cut-and-pasteable code.

You can find a good Google Transliteration API example [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ow6Lmd7dcZY/trunk/language/language/test/com/google/gwt/language/client/transliteration/text/TransliterationTest.java&q=com.google.gwt.language.client.transliteration.text.Transliteration&d=8). You'll want to add your custom code in the part of the code that looks like this:

```
new TransliterationCallback() {

@Override
protected void onCallback(TransliterationResult result) {
// your code here
}

});
```

Comment: Thank you Brent for your reply and help.                             What if I want to use google translitration api as in a desk-top application with the same idea (to transliterate data from "inputfile.txt" for example and put the output in an "outputfile.txt".)